# I have been asked this particular number theory question in an interview.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was asked a question as such i am a shopkeeper having six weights 8,4,2,1,1/2,1/4 kg. Now i have to calculate the sum of all the possible different combinations of weights and no combinations should be repeated. I was given 15 minutes to figure it out but was unable to solve it. Can anybody suggest the approach.

Comment: The important think to note is that because the weights are all powers of 2 there are no 2 combinations that will give you the same total weight. The question is therefore reduced to the number of combinations for picking n items out of 6.

Comment: There are 63 different combinations possible.. I hope they did not expect you to calculate them all! {Out of 6, choose 1 weight ; out of 6,choose 2 weights,...; out of 6, choose all}.

Answer (score 5):

In units of $\frac14$ kg the weights are $32,16,8,4,2$, and $1$. Each combination of weights corresponds to the representation in base two of some number. For example, the combination of $2,4$, and $32$ corresponds to the binary number $100110$. The largest such number is $111111_{\text{two}}$, or $63$ in ordinary decimal notation. Thus, I can weigh any whole number of quarter kilograms from $0$ through $63$. The total is therefore

$$0+1+2+3\ldots+63=\sum_{k=0}^{63}k=\frac{63(63+1)}2=2016\;,$$

but that’s in units of $\frac14$ kg, so the total in kilograms is $2016\cdot\dfrac14=504$ kg.

Answer (score 4):

You have the sum of the given numbers is $8+4+2+1+1/2+1/4=15+3/4=63/4$

There are $6$ different weights, so $2^6$ different combinations. However, for each weight, $2^5$ combinations include that particular weight, while $2^5$ do not. Since the sum is over a finite number of terms, we are free to order them how we wish. Hence, we can simply count each weight $2^5$ times. So, the sum of all combinations is $2^5\cdot \frac{63}{4}=504$.

Answer (score 1):

Each subset of the weights has a dual subset given by its complement. There are $2^6$ subsets but we're pairing them. Hence the sum is $2^5 \cdot63/4 = 8 \cdot 63=504$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that they are all powers of $2$, ranging from $2^0 \times \frac 14$ to $2^5 \times \frac 14$.  If you are familiar with binary representations, you can make all weights from $1$ to $63 \times \frac 14$.  Then $\sum_{i=1}^{63}\frac i4=\frac 18\cdot 63 \cdot 64$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can approach it. Note that when choosing whether or not each weight is included in a particular combination, we have two choices (yes and no) for each of the six weights. In particular, then, each weight can be included in $2^5$ different combinations. (Why?) Consequently, adding up $8+4+2+1+\frac12+\frac14=\frac{63}4$ and multiplying by $2^5=32$ gives us our answer of $504$ kg.

---

The above is under the assumption that you are supposed to take the sum of all possible combinations of the weights *in the sense of adding up the weights of each combination.*

If instead you are simply supposed to calculate the *number* of possible weights that can be obtained as a combination of the individual weights, then we will proceed a bit differently. Note that since each weight is an integer power of $2$, and since weights can't be repeated (so we can't use two one-pound weights, for example), then each obtainable weight can only be obtained *in one way*. For instance, $\frac72$ kg can only be obtained by $2+1+\frac12.$ Consequently, each obtainable weight is uniquely determined by which of the individual weights is included. There are $6$ weights, and (as above) only two choices about whether or not to include them, so there are $2^6=64$ possible weights that can be obtained from conbinations of the individual weights. This includes the weight $0$ kg, which we get from including *none* of the weights, so if that is an undesirable outcome, then the answer would instead be $63$.

Comment: What about the combination when I just choose 2 kgs? I will have 2 kgs and not 504 kgs!!

Comment: We are adding up *all* possible sums, though. That is, we are considering $$\left(\frac14\right)+\left(\frac12\right)+(1)+(2)+(4)+(8)+\left(\frac12+ \frac14\right)+\left(1+\frac14\right)+...$$ Adding *all of those together* gets us $504$. Since each of the weights occurs in a sum $2^5$ times, then we can more simply obtain the total by $$2^5\left(\frac14+\frac12+1+2+4+8\right).$$

Comment: The kicker is to remember that finite summation is commutative and associative (so we can rearrange terms), and that we have distributivity of multiplication over addition (so we can factor out that $2^5$).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pick any combination out of 6. It is $2^6 = 64$.
Once you understand that every combination is unique it is a simple interview question.

This includes the zero weight option (having not selected anything), which should be mentioned in the interview or use 63.